# Как найти минимальное число, большее 0 и не входящее в исходный массив?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Найти минимальное натуральное число (положительное, целое, большее `0`), которого нет в исходном массиве `A`.

Например:

Для `A = [1, 3]` ответ: `2`

Для `A = [1, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2]` ответ: `5`

Comment: Отсортируй массив и в один проход найди ответ.

Comment: Я так делаю, но что-то пока не получается. Вы не могли бы подсказать как сделать?

Comment: Что не получается-  отсортировать?

Comment: Взаимоисключающие параграфы: "найти в этом массиве число, которого нет в этом массиве"? Поправьте условие.

Comment: Условие так и есть т.е. найти в массиве минимальное число, которое нет в массиве. Например А {1, 3} - Ответ: 2.

Comment: *Я так делаю, но что-то пока не получается* Что, правда не можете определить, что именно не получается - отсортировать или найти отсутствующее число?

Comment: Не могу найти отсутствующее число...

Comment: Посмотрите на сортированные массивы, в одном из которых есть числа от 1 до 5, а в другом от 1 до 6, и пропущено 3. Как отловить вторую ситуацию? Что нужно соотнести друг с другом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моё компактное и красивое решение без лишних сортировок

```
int mas[] = {1, -1, 7, 0, 1, 2, 4};
int length = sizeof(mas) / sizeof(mas[0]);
int res = 1;
for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (mas[i] == res) {
            res++;
            break;
        }
    }
cout<<res;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ну вот я так и не понял, первый цикл, зачем он нужен?

Comment: неправильно будет работать ваше компактгое и красивое решение

Comment: Компактное, красивое, _медленное_ решение, зато без лишних сортировок!

Comment: Два цикла нужно для того, чтобы по каждому элементу массива пройти с каждым значением переменно res.
@int3, согласен сложность этого алгоритма больше, чем того, что привели Вы. Но мое решение визуально выглядит более понятным чем ваше. Но это уже пусть автор сам выбирает то решение, что будет для него удобным именно в его ситуации

Comment: @RealPeha я вообще не приводил решения, но абсолютно согласен с тем, что сортировать - это правильный подход

Comment: @ARHovsepyan: *"неправильно будет работать"* на каком вводе?

Comment: @jfs, во первых неучтен  факт, что в массиве могут быть несколько обьектов с одинаковым значением

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, в массиве приведенном в коде {1, -1, 7, 0, 1, 2, 4} есть повторяющаяся единичка. Проблем с ней нету. Только что проверил на других вариантах массива - все работает

Comment: @ARHovsepyan: вы мне просто ввод приведите (можно без объяснений), [как я к вашему решению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813579/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b5-0-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2/813644?noredirect=1#comment1291933_813633).

Comment: @ jfs, я вам ничего не обязан доказывать...  я выразил свое мнение, вы говорите свое,  а  мне не охота проводить дискуссию на тему программы школьного уровня

Comment: @ jfs, а вот грубить не нужно,  как то невоспитанно себя ведете, причем грубиите, а потом удаляете  коммент, и после этого называете подлостью поступок других... Смешной вы человечек

Comment: @ARHovsepyan кто комментарий удалил не знаю. Грубости там не помню, только факты: вы бездоказательно (без оснований назвали ответ неправильным), имея при этом свой сломанный ответ к тому же вопросу (результат что правильный ответ с минусом, а неправильный в плюсе—это вредительство). Я это считаю подлостью. Если этот комментарий кто-то удалит. Пишите¶ Не нужно пробел после \@ ставить, что за детский сад.

Comment: Комментарий был и был удалён. Судя по всему он был автоматически удалён системой после проставления на нём флага из-за совпадения какого-то слова из него со списком из "плохих" слов, которые Николас добавлял в какой-то там скрипт автоматического удаления.

Answer (score 2):

На `C++` не писатель, но могу предложить два варианта:

***Исходные данные***:

```
int a[ 6 ] = { 1, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2 };
int size = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( a[ 0 ] );
```

***Вариант 1:***

т.к. по условию число должно быть больше `0`, то начиная с `1` проверяем все числа, которые не входят в массив. Первое и будет тем самым.

```
int min = 1;

while (true)
{
    bool isContain = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (min == a[ i ])
        {
            isContain = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isContain)
    {
        min++;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << min << "\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

***Вариант 2:***

Сначала сортируем исходный массив (по возрастанию в данном случае), и проверяем разность соседних элементов. Если получаем:

- `0` - элементы равны;
- `1` - элементы идут по порядку;
- `2` и более - значит в этом диапазоне и находится минимальный элемент.

Прибавляем `1` к элементу, который находится левее в паре - это значение и будет минимальным.

```
for (int j = 1; j < size; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - j; i++)
    {
        if (a[ i ] > a[ i + 1 ])
        {
            int b = a[ i ];
            a[ i ] = a[ i + 1 ];
            a[ i + 1 ] = b;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    if (a[ i ] - a[ i - 1 ] > 1)
    {
        std::cout << a[ i - 1 ] + 1 << "\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не ясно зачем квадратичный алгоритм для сортировки использовать. Как есть второй вариант не работает. Для `a[] = {-1};` ожидалось: `1` вывод, а [ничего не выводит](https://ideone.com/j6oQus)

Answer (score 1):

берите число  `n = 1 ;`  Ищите в массиве это число. Если оно есть, то  `++n`; и  повторяем по циклу, пока не будет в массиве такого числа.

Или сортируйте массив, и допустим он имеет размер `10`:

```
const int sz = 10;
int m[10];
// инициализация, потом сортировка 
int k = 1;    
for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
    if ( m[i] == k )  {
        if (m[i] == m[i +1]) continue;            
          ++k;            
    }
    else  {         
        cout << "это число:  " << k;            
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: решение не работает для `int m[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};`. Ожидаемый вывод: `2`. Ваш код выводит: [`это число:  1`](https://ideone.com/CrCrrI).

Comment: Я и не говорил, что я написал красивый код, где учтены все обстоятельства. Я этого делать и не должен, поскольку  я просто  предлогаю вариант и не тестирую  и сопроваждаю, а потом сдаю код на проверку,  не  пишу за кого то код.

Comment: решение неверное. Причём здесь красота. Ответ просто неправильный

Answer (score 1):

Линейный алгоритм:

1. отметить все числа в интервале `[1, n]`, которые есть во входном массиве, где `n` это размер массива
2. найти первое неотмеченное число.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  // read numbers
  std::istream_iterator<int> numbers {std::cin}, eof;
  std::vector<int> arr(numbers, eof);

  // mark numbers in [1, n] range that are in the array
  size_t n = arr.size();
  std::vector<bool> m(n+1, false);
  for (int x : arr)
    if (1 <= x && x <= n)
      m[x-1] = true;

  // find the first absent number (position + 1)
  auto it = std::find(std::begin(m), std::end(m), false);
  std::cout << (std::distance(std::begin(m), it) + 1) << std::endl;
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/w9qxHK).

Comment: вектора и другие контейнера не обсуждались, вопрос касался массивам

Comment: не нужно придумывать. В вопросе нет никаких ограничений на использование вектора. В примере ввод читается со стандартного ввода, из статического массива ещё проще было бы взять ввод¶ То что я вам на ошибку  в вашем решении указал, что оно не работает, ещё не значит, что на другие правильные рабочие ответы (на ссылку в ответе нажмите) нужно минусы ставить. Я смотрю ещё кто-те не поленился минус  ответу двухлетней давности поставить. Мелкий пакостник однако попался.

Comment: я хотел сказать шагов, а не памяти

Answer (score 0):

Можно для входящего массива размера n создать вспомогательный битовый массив размера n. Потом в первом цикле проходить через входящий массив, отбрасывая все числа больше n и меньше 1, а для числа x входящего в промежуток от 1 до n устанавливать бит (x-1) элемента второго массива в 1.
Во втором цикле проходить вспомогательный массив и при первом значении с нулевым битом останавливаться, потом к индексу прибавляем 1 и получаем искомое число.

Answer (score 0):

Задача имеет классическое решение за линейное время (быстрее чем сортировка) и без дополнительной памяти (не нужны дополнительные массивы флагов и т.п.). С другой стороны содержимое массива меняется, в каком-то смысле это сортировка специального вида.

Идём по массиву и если видим элемент, который можно поместить на своё место, делаем это. В конце прохода все элементы для которых это возможно стоят на своих местах (`v[i] == i + 1`). Если в каком-то месте равенство нарушено, числа `i + 1` в массиве нет.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

int absent_number(std::vector<int> &v) {
    const int n = v.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        while (1 <= v[i] && v[i] <= n && v[v[i] - 1] != v[i]) {
            std::swap(v[i], v[v[i] - 1]);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (v[i] != i + 1) {
            return i + 1;
        }
    }
    return n + 1;
}

void test(std::vector<int> v) {
    std::cout << '\n';
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n' << absent_number(v) << '\n';
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    test({1, 3});
    test({1, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2});
    test({1, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2});
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 absent-number.cpp && ./a.out 
>
> 1 3 
> 2
> 1 3 
>
> 1 4 6 1 3 2 
> 5
> 1 2 3 4 1 6 
>
> 1 4 6 5 3 2 
> 7
> 1 2 3 4 5 6
> ```